# Declaring keys ("key1" | "key2") first and then enforcing that another object type must have those keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Usually in typescript you'd use the pattern that you declare a type:

`type O = {"key1": string, "key2": int}`

and then you can declare

`type keyNames = keyof O`

But is it possible to do the opposite? i.e. I start out with `keyNames` and then I declare that `type O` must have the keys in the `keyNames`.

This is useful in the case when `o` is a big type definition and I want to have all the keys on a single line in source code rather than having to scroll.

But at the same time, I'd like to be notified by the compiler if I miss one key when declaring `O`, or if I misspell one, etc.

Comment: Possibly `Record<keyNames, string>` which is an object whose keys are type `keyNames` and values are string. The problem is there's not a way to specific the types of certain key values.

Answer (score 1):

`Record<KeyNames, unknown>` will match types with at least the keys of `KeyNames`.